# Get the all childs of the parent id using spark graph frame motif search

Tags: apache-spark, motif

I am using apache spark to create graphframe using motif query.
I have created required edges and vertices and after that executing motif query on lookup pattern. I need to fetch all childs of a particular node with its subchilds.For example:

```
// Vertex DataFrame
val v = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60)
)).toDF("id", "name", "age")
// Edge DataFrame
val e = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
  ("f", "c", "follow"),
  ("e", "f", "follow"),
  ("e", "d", "friend"),
  ("d", "a", "friend"),
  ("a", "e", "friend")
)).toDF("src", "dst", "relationship")
// Create a GraphFrame
val g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

Now if I will click on node a then i should get all child and subchild of a.

Comment: where is the data and code?

Comment: data is very big ...can you tell me only look up pattern to find all childs and subchilds  of parent using motif search ?

Comment: you can share an example dataset that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @mtoto i have edited question with example dataset...please help me.

Comment: what is your expected output and what have you tried? You cannot `"click"` on nodes.

Comment: @mtoto Expected output = > how i can get  childs and subchilds of a. 
I am trying code => DataFrame motifs = graph.find(pattern) , so here tell me pattern to get expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146137/discussion-between-avinash-chavan-and-mtoto).